# Is this a papaya? What kind, and how do I know when it is ripe?

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, fruits, tropical, papaya

There are several trees with these fruits growing wild near where I'm staying in the Caribbean. I let one ripen from green to orange and cut it open.  Is it a papaya?  And what kind? This one didn't taste too good.  Did I let it ripen too long, or is this type just not as good as others?[image]

Comment: Good question and good illustration; if could include an overall illustration of the tree, its approximate height, if there is a similar tree nearby that isn't bearing fruit, close illustrations of the trees' flowers, and the size of the fruit, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like papaya. The outer skin in the second photo looks like it has some greenish flecks which indicate it is not fully ripe. Leave fruit to go fully yellow all over and then pick. Use nose and softness of outer skin to judge. Papaya needs to be cut when fully ripe, otherwise it will taste a bit flat; they may not continue to ripen after cutting unless exposed to ethylene from a banana or similar. You may just be unlucky with that tree - the fruit looks small compared to commercial varieties; that may or may not be a bad thing.